# jQuery Animate - Sidebar In / Out - Odd Behavour

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

1. I have been experimenting using jQuery animate to slide a sidebar div 'in/out' from the left of the screen when an open/close link is clicked. This works fine.
2. Next I wanted to animate the sidebar div out when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the sidebar div, this also works fine.
3. The problem occurs when I then try to click the open link again after the last animation has faded the sidebar out. (After pt.2 has run)

When I click the open link, I get a delay of about 3-4 seconds, I cannot figure out what I have done wrong, really would appreciate some pointers as have become rather stuck on my approach now.

Thanks.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/fRFCN/5/

1) Click open 
2) Scroll down 
3) Sidebar fades 
4) Click Open again 
5) Wait 5-8 seconds then the sidebar appears. 
Step 4 is the delay error.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

jQuery(".open a").on("click", function() { 

    jQuery('.sidebar').animate({
          'opacity': '1',
          right: '+=0'
    },300);

    return false; 

});


jQuery('.close').on('click', function() {            
        jQuery('.sidebar').animate({
              'opacity': '0',
              right: '+=0'
        },300);

        return false; 

 });


var element = jQuery('.sidebar');

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop() + jQuery(window).height();
    var offset = element.offset().top + element.height();

    if (scroll > offset) {

        jQuery('.sidebar').animate({
              'opacity': '0',
              right: '+=0'
        },600);

    } 

});

});
```

Comment: If you're using a modern version of jQuery, it's time to dump the livequery plugin.

Comment: I strongly recommend using latest jQuery and [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of the **very** old `livequery` plugin if possible

Comment: Thanks, will do. Good point.

Comment: If you have any more problems, please ask another question or edit this one.

Comment: Thanks @andyb, I have updated the code, but still get a strangely large delay after the user has scrolled below the sidebar div and then clicked the open link.

Comment: Please can you add the corresponding HTML and CSS to the question? If you want, you could also make a demo on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Thanks @andyb, I have made a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fRFCN/5) 1) Click open 2) Scroll down 3) Sidebar fades 4) Click Open again 5) Wait 5-8 seconds then the sidebar appears. Step 4 is the delay error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the `scroll` code firing *every time* the window is scrolled, either up or down, so it is queuing up **a lot** of animation events to hide the sidebar, which are still running and *hiding* the sidebar even after scrolling back to the top. So the next *open* will be last in a long queue, hence the variable time delay in opening again.

```
$('#pullout').animate({
    'opacity': '0',
    right: '+=0'
},600);
```

One way to solve this is to add a condition to stop the animation being added more than once, for example:

```
var element = $('#pullout');

if (scroll > offset && $('#pullout').css('opacity') == 1) {
    $('#pullout').animate({
    'opacity': '0',
        right: '+=0'
    },600);
}
```